# apache apply rewrite rules to only one subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following directory structure:

```
/var/www/html
    --myapp
    --phpmyadmin
```

In the /var/www/html folder there is a .htaccess file with following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.sk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.sk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myapp/public
RewriteRule (.*) /myapp/public/$1 [L]
```

If I access the http://mydomain.sk the rewrite rules work as expected and I get the myapp/public/index.php file as root. However, if I want to access http://mydomain.sk/phpmyadmin the request is redirected to http://mydomain/myapp/public/phpmyadmin. Here I get the error 404 - page not found.

I cannot find a way to only serve http://mydomain.sk/myapp/public as a root folder and to serve http://mydomain.sk/phpmyadmin "as is".

Answer (score 0):

It took some time to figure this one out. The rules posted above actually work as expected. It turns out I had another set of rewrite rules in apache2.conf file (that I totally forgot about) that took precedence over my .htaccess file.